# Let G1 be abelian group of order 6 and G2=S3

Tags: group-theory

Let $G_1$ be abelian group of  order $6$ and $G_2=S_3$..For $j=1,2$, let $P_j$ be the statement:
"$G_j$ has a unique subgroup of order $2$.then which of the following satement is true?
a) both $P_1$ and $P_2$ are holds
b)neither $P_1$ nor $P_2$ holds
c)$P_1$ holds but $P_2$ not
d)$P_2$ holds but $P_1$ not

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: $|G_1| = 2 \cdot 3$ is the product of two distinct primes and thus $G_1$ is cyclic. Also note that $\{\text{Id}, \, (1 \ 2) \}$ and $\{\text{Id}, \, (2 \ 3)\}$ are subgroups of $S_3$ of order 2.

Comment: thanks...sir I have an question..If a group is  order of product of two distinct prime then it is cyclic?as for elxample 11 X13 =143..a group of order 143 is cyclic?

Answer (score 0):

$G_1 \simeq \Bbb Z_6 = \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$. Here only subgroup of order $2$ is $\{0,3\}$.

Also $G_2=S_3=\{e,(1 \quad 2),(1 \quad 3),(2 \quad 3),(1 \quad 2 \quad 3),(1 \quad 3 \quad 2)\}$. Here $\{e,(1 \quad 2)\}$,$\{e,(2 \quad 3)\}$ and $\{e,(1 \quad 3)\}$ are the only subgroups of order $2$.